# Uninstall exceptions in InstallShield

Tags: deployment, installation, installshield

I have a setup project with InstallShield 2010. I'm deploying a configuration file during installation. However, when uninstalled, InstallShield decides to delete it (which is normal).

The question is, is there a way to keep the file on the hard disk even after the application in uninstalled? I don't want to reconfigure the application every time the user uninstalls/installs.

**Edit**: I'm using MSI project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what project type you are using.   Either way, put the config file in it's own component.  For MSI projects, set the Permanent attribute to true.  For InstallScript projects, set the Uninstall attribute to false.